# Как получить неповторяющиеся значения из таблицы

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть таблица. Нужно получить только уникальные неповторяющиеся данные, со статусом 1

```
hours            id_status
2021-08-01 06:00    1
2021-08-01 08:00    1
2021-08-01 07:00    2
2021-08-01 08:00    2
2021-08-01 09:00    2
```

На выходе должно получиться

```
2021-08-01 06:00    1
```

Comment: *Нужно получить только уникальные неповторяющиеся данные ... На выходе должно получиться* ??? Имеется в виду, что (1) hours уникально по всей таблице безотносительно к status (2) status = 1? иначе невозможно объяснить, почему не выведена вторая запись...

Answer (score 0):

Используй DISTINCT:

```
SELECT DISTINCT min(date(hours)) FROM your_table_name;
```

функции преобразования подбери нужные.